# Create a subfolder

Tags: php

When I add a new user manually it should create a folder with the users Id and when images are uploaded it should be in his (`advertiser_images/userid`) user id folder and should be captured on the database as well.

Here is the code:

```
<?php

$data = array();
$data = $_POST["data"];

mkdir("advertiser_images/".$data[0]);

?>
```

Comment: Looks like you forgot the code

Comment: That looks bad. You're opening yourself up to a bad time if you let the user specify what folder to create with `$_POST`...

Comment: Aside from security, what do you actually need help with?

Comment: No the folder should be automatically assigned to his user id

Comment: Enable `error_reporting`. Then investigate parent folder permissions.

Comment: how do I enable error-reporting

Comment: how do I enable error_reporting

Comment: Put `ini_set('display_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top of the page.

Answer (score 1):

> Disclaimer: **never** do this with raw user data!

To create subdirectories automatically, you should set the `recursive` param of `mkdir()` to `true`:

```
<?php
    $path = sprintf('advertiser_images/%s', $_POST['data'][0]);

    mkdir($path, 0755, true);
?>
```

See [docs](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php).